# Why does the Sigmoid function use e?

Tags: analysis, exponential-function

From what I can guess, because the [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) uses $S(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$, I would think that there would be some connection with the fact that the derivative of $e^x$ is itself. What that connection is (assuming I'm not just on the wrong track all together), I am uncertain of.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+ a^{-x}} =\frac{1}{1+ e^{-x \ln a}} = S(x \ln a)$ so you can replace $e$ by any real-number $> 1$ it will simply stretch the function and will multiply the derivative by $\ln a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a different constant that is the same as rescaling $x$

$$
b^{-x} = (e^{\ln b})^{-x} = e^{ - x\ln b}
$$

So rename $x\ln b \to x$. Might as well use $e$ because that is the one that makes the differential equation look nicer.

Comment: That being said, why not just simplify it to $\frac{1}{1+c^{-x}}$, where c represents an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Yes, if you want. It will just control the width. But that's equally simple rather than simpler.

Comment: so why e and not 2 (for instance) then ?